# refs/heads/master is unchanged when trying to remove a large file from git history

Tags: git, github

I accidentally put several files greater than 100M into my GitHub repo, and I tried to push it and it failed. After reading some online posts, I realize I need to remove that big file from git history. I followed procedure as described here https://help.github.com/en/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository. But I got the warning as shown below, and this method didn't work out. So what's the reason that /heads/master, /remotes/origin/master is unchanged? Thanks a lot!

```
C:\Users\10453\source\repos\subgenomeAssignment>git filter-branch --force --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch ./gene Density/Nitab.1-12.gff" --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
Rewrite 2c09639875bee25f33e5233badd74552667d0e33 (47/48) (31 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)
WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' is unchanged
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two files are named `./gene` and `Density/Nitab.1-12.gff`?

(Remember, filter-branch passes your commands through a *shell*, and shells break arguments at spaces.)

If the file is actually named `gene Density/Nitab.1-12.gff`, with a space within it, you'll need to quote the file name.  This requires a different set of quotes than you're already using, as your command-line shell removes one set of quotes.  So:

```
git filter-branch --force \
    --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch 'gene Density/Nitab.1-12.gff'" \
    --prune-empty \
    --tag-name-filter cat \
    -- \
    --all
```

for instance might do the trick.  (I've put each set of arguments on a line by itself, with backslash-newline to indicate that the shell should keep going, mostly for readability—you can still do this all as a single line; the key is to add the quotes.  I also removed the `./` as it's usually pointless to specify `./`, especially in a filter-branch fragment where the commands are always run from the top level of the repository.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out I need another set of quotations inside! That solves the problem.